# build a List from a Map through Map.iter function in F#

Tags: list, f#, dictionary

I have the following types:

```
type ColorCounter = 
    {

        Count : int
        Color : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color 

    }

let AvailableColors : Map<uint32,ColorCounter> = .....
```

I would like to iterate through the Map and return a List . I wrote the following function that doesn't compile:

```
let AvailableColorList(map : Map<uint32,ColorCounter>) : List<Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color> = 
     let colorSeq = seq {

        map |> Map.iter (fun key col -> yield col.Color)  
     }
     colorSeq |> Seq.toList
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong with the syntax of the function passed to iter, but I've not find any suitable example that shows me how to do that.

Could anyone help me?What's my error? How can I fix the code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this

```
let AvailableColorList(map : Map<uint32,ColorCounter>) = 
    ResizeArray(map |> Seq.map (fun (KeyValue(_, col)) -> col.Color))
```

You're mixing a sequence comprehension and map, which are two different ways of doing the same thing.

You could also write it this way

```
let AvailableColorList(map : Map<uint32,ColorCounter>) = 
    ResizeArray([ for KeyValue(_, col) in map -> col.Color ])
```

Comment: well, thanks for the answer. But I still don't understand why it doesn't compile if I specify the return type of AvailableColorList as List<Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color>.

Comment: And actually it seems to return a (ColorCounter->Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color) list rather than a List<Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color> . Am I wrong?

Comment: If you want `System.Collection.Generic.List<T>` (which is aliased as `ResizeArray<T>` in F#) you can do: `ResizeArray([ for KeyValue(_, col) in map -> col.Color ])`

Comment: Actually your second solution works even specifying the return type. It's the first one that seems different. Sorry for the insistence, but I'm really trying to understand this language.

Comment: If the first function has a return type of `List<ColorCounter -> Color>` then I think I know what's going on. It's saying it's a list of functions that take a ColorCounter and return a Color. The signature of the Seq.map function is wrong. Each item in the sequence is going to be either a `(uint32 * ColorCounter)` tuple, or it will be a `KeyValuePair<uint32, ColorCounter>`. In either case, that single item containing two values is passed to the first (ignored) parameter in `(fun _ col -> col.Color)`. The result of only supplying one parameter is a function that takes the other parameter.

Comment: Given all that, one of the following two should work: `Seq.map (fun (_, col) -> col.Color)` (this one takes a single tuple parameter and deconstructs it, instead of taking two parameters). Or: `Seq.map (fun KeyValue(_, col) -> col.Color)` (this one takes a KeyValuePair and deconstructs it using the KeyValue active pattern).

Comment: I think there may be some confusion about [F# lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx) vs [.NET Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) (aka, [`ResizeArrays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353447.aspx)).

Comment: I forgot to use `KeyValue` in the first one. It's fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
let AvailableColors : Map<uint32,ColorCounter> = Map.empty
let colors = [ for (KeyValue(_, v)) in AvailableColors -> v ]
```